# how to display text recognition bounding box on screen of a ARFrame captured image? (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, avcapturesession, text-recognition

I've read ARKit official tutorial **RealtimeNumberReader**, it uses **AVCaptureSession** and a specific function **layerRectConverted** which is only for **AVCaptureSession** to convert coordinates from bounding box to screen coordinate.

```
let rect = layer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: box.applying(self.visionToAVFTransform))
```

Now I want to recognize text on **ARFrame**'s **capturedImage** and then display the bound box on screen. Is it possible?

I know how to recognize text on a single image from official [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_text_in_images), my problem is how to convert the normalized box coordinate to viewport coordinate.

Please help and thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try looking at this git repo.](https://github.com/tucan9389/TextDetection-CoreML) Having messed with it myself it is not the most performant but this should give you a start.

Comment: Thank you very much! Based on your example, I've finally figured out the solution. I'll make another answer to explain for other people who may need.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Banane42's answer, I found the theory behind `ARkit` and `VNRecognizeTextRequest`

1. ARKit Sceneview's `capturedImage` is wider than you can see. check the picture below. I made a small app that has an `imageView` to display the whole image, and the background image is the sceneview area.
   [image: an image to proof arkit's capturedimage size]

2. The coordinate of sceneview or image is originated from `top left` corner, `x-axis` -> to right and `y-axis` -> to bottom. But the coordinate of `boundingBox` that `VNRequest` returns is originated from `bottom left` corner and `x-axis` -> to right and `y-axis` -> to top.
3. if you use `request.regionOfInterest`, this ROI should be normalized coordinate with respect to the whole image. the returned `VNRequest boundingBox` is in normalized coordinate with respect to the ROI box.

Finally I've got my app working properly. And this is very complicated. so be careful!
[image]